# JPA: Result list - Cast Object[] to tuple

Tags: java, jpa, entity

simple question, but I don't see my error in reasoning. Having a named query with selected members as result instead of the entire row/entity.

Now I want to access the member fields with the convenient tuple methods.

```
q = em.createNamedQuery("test.findvar");
List<Tuple> tuples = q.getResultList();    
for (Tuple t : tuples)
   System.out.println(t.get(0) + " " + t.get(1));
```

Unfortunately it throws me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to javax.persistence.Tuple
```

All works fine with:

```
q = em.createNamedQuery("test.findvar");
List<Object[]> objs = q.getResultList();    
for (Object[] obj : objs)
    System.out.println(obj[0] + " " + obj[1]);
```

What's wrong with my first solution?

Comment: Are you sure `q.getResultList();` is returning `List<Tuple>` what I see from second solution is that it's returning List of Arrays of Objects and not tuple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify return type in createNamedQuery(), as noted in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)

So your code should look like:

```
q = em.createNamedQuery("test.findvar", Tuple.class);
List<Tuple> tuples = q.getResultList();    
for (Tuple t : tuples)
   System.out.println(t.get(0) + " " + t.get(1));
```

When you specify return type, [TypedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) instance is created, instead of [Query](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) instance. Query does not use generics and returns simply java.util.List.

Comment: Let me correct, it dosn't as expected: List<Tuple> tuples = em.createNamedQuery("getInfo", Tuple.class).setParameter("param",1).getResultList(); followed by tuples.get(0).getClass() gives me a "ClassCastException" - "Object cannot be cast to javax.persistence.Tuple"

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 OpenJDK 1.8.0, EJB 3.2, Payara (Glassfish) 5.183, putting Tuple.class as the second argument to createNamedQuery has no effect. It compiles fine, but the getResultList() call still returns List<Object[]>.

Also, the new getResultStream() method returns a Stream<Object[]>, with or without the Tuple.class arg.

Worse, the compiler doesn't seem to know the type of objects being streamed or used from the list (a bug IMO), so any attempt to actually use the returned query values will give compiler errors unless the value is explicitly cast.